# How to set breakpoint in TensorFlow uniform replay buffer?

Tags: python, tensorflow, tf-agent

I'm using tensorflow2 and dealing with `tf_agents.replay_buffers.TFUniformReplayBuffer`.
As the comments of source codes suggest, each block of the replay buffer is consisted of several episodes:

```
The TFUniformReplayBuffer stores episodes in `B == batch_size` blocks of
size `L == max_length`, with total frame capacity `C == L * B`.  
Storage looks like:

block1 ep1 frame1
           frame2
       ...
       ep2 frame1
           frame2
       ...
       <L frames total>
block2 ep1 frame1
           frame2
       ...
       ep2 frame1
           frame2
       ...
       <L frames total>
...
blockB ep1 frame1
           frame2
       ...
       ep2 frame1
           frame2
       ...
       <L frames total>
```

What I need to do is to manually write into a replay buffer, frame by frame. Each frame is an instance of `tf_agents.trajectories.Trajectory`.

**I wonder whether there exists something serving as a breakpoint in TFUniformReplayBuffer to seperate each episode in a block?** So that when I read data from the replay buffer with `num_step>1`, I won't get a mixed sequence composed of frames from different episodes, say, the last frame of episode1 and the first frame of episode2. **And, if there do exist such thing, how can I set it manually?**

Thanks